# db best practices: data + boolean column or just data?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a table in my Postgres database for a set of games. Each game can either be maintained by an administrator or have no administrator. If the game has an administrator, there will be an `admin_id` field which contains the id of the administrator.

My first thought is having an `admin_id` data field which is `NULL` if the game has no administrator. If the game does have an admin, `admin_id` will contain a user id of type integer. Like such:

```
admin_id
--------
15282    -- admin
9283     -- admin
NULL     -- no admin
81234    -- admin
```

The other alternative is an additional boolean column, i.e. `has_admin`, which is true and false for obvious reasons:

```
has_admin | admin_id 
----------|----------
true      | 15282     
true      | 9283     
false     | NULL
true      | 81234
```

My question is, is the `has_admin` column just unnecessary fluff? Or are there valid reasons to keep it there, if, for example, I'll be querying the database frequently to find whether games have admins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `has_admin` is a kind of de-normalisation, and you therefore risk introducing anomalies such as:

```
true      | NULL     
false     | 9283
```

It is sometimes necessary to do such things due to efficiency reasons, but in this case you can easily derive `has_admin` as:

```
admin_id is not null
```

so there really is no reason to add such attribute

Answer (score 1):

Well, a Boolean does not really take much space, so this would not cause any issue size-wise.
However, it is cumbersome to have has_admin, because like you said:

```
if ($obj->admin_id){
    // do stuff
}
```

is the same as:

```
if ($obj->has_admin === true){
    // do stuff
}
```

And since it is necessary to always check what you get from your db

```
if ($obj->has_admin === true && $obj->admin_id){
    // do stuff
}
```

which is totally useless :)

Hope this helps